# PHP Regex to match multiline

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to build a pattern to match a multiline code

```
    $data['infos'] = array();
    foreach ($infos as $info) {
        $data['infos'][] = array(
            'title' => $special['title'],
            'text'  => $special['summary'],,
        );
    }
    $data['next'] = $this->url('page/next');
    $data['page'] = $this->url('page/curent');
```

my attempt was to use `(\$data\['infos']\[] = array\(\n).*\n\t.*\n\t*\)\;` but it did not work, but when i tried `(\$data\['infos']\[] = array\()` only this part was match

`$data['infos'][] = array(`

how do i build the pattern to match this part only

```
        $data['infos'][] = array(
            'title' => $special['title'],
            'text'  => $special['summary'],,
        );
```

also i love to see it simple so that i can modify it for other similar case.have been on it for a whole day with no luck, kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [something like this](https://www.regex101.com/r/uVhqhU/2) would be sufficient. Depends on your input.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it, so such nice tool, i remove the global option `gs` and add `s` and it works like charm

Comment: kindly post it as answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a simple pattern would be sufficient depends on how your input could look like.

```
$re = '~\Q$data[\'infos\'][]\E.*?\);~s';
```

- `\Q`...`\E` is used to match literally (also could escape the brackets/dollar).
- `.*?` in *single line mode* (`s` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)) matches [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) any amount of [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/uVhqhU/2) or [php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/711837)